# Is noscript mandatory for worldwide compliance page compliance?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, script, webpage

I tested a random page of mine with javascript on achecker.ca four times: once using the "Stanca Act" guideline in the scanning options, once using the "Section 508" guideline, once using the "WCAG 1.0 (Level A)" guideline, and once using the "BITV 1.0 (level 2)" guideline, and in each test, I receive the following error:

```
Check 90: script must have a noscript section. 

Repair: Add a noscript section immediately following the script that provides the same functionality as the script.  Line 1, Column 715: 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" a ...
```

When I checked it with the rest of the guidelines, there's no issue with the noscript tag.

Do I really need to have a noscript tag for each script tag to make my webpage worldwide compatible or are the guidelines I mentioned that reported the issues now a joke?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant guideline from [WCAG 1.0 Level A](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/) is:

> Ensure that pages are usable when scripts, applets, or other programmatic objects are turned off or not supported. If this is not possible, provide equivalent information on an alternative accessible page.

Providing a `<noscript>` section is one way to approach this guideline, but it isn't a very good way. Scripts can fail for [reasons other than when scripts as "turned off or not supported"](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

A better approach for following the guideline is to write [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

**The guideline is fine. The test which your tool is applying to see if you are following the guideline is poor.**

In this particular case, the content isn't even real content: it is an advert and not required for the reader to understand the content of the page.